# How much Facebook Public Data is available via their API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am curious as to how much data can be gathered using the fql or graph api from facebook. If the user has their info marked as public and I am not friends with them, i can see it on the site.  However, i have just paid for a completed project someone did for me and the interface they designed does not get that data.  For instance, their likes.  I was told the api does not support all facebook data, but that seems wrong to me.

Comment: I'm not sure on the extent of data available, however, I know for a fact you can get likes for posts. Although you can only 'like' a post and not pictures, albums, checkins.. The only experience I have had with facebook dev has been playing around with the javascript sdk though

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for the graph api. Hopefully this will help you discover what data is available.

Comment: ok, i see that 'likes' is not on that list, so i can assume that even if it is public, the graph api will not allow me to pull it down.  is there another way to get more data if you 'connect' an application to facebook?  if i am loggin in myself and can see data, i want to be able to have an application get it as well.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I was using the javascript SDK and used fql to get the likes of every post on the news feed.

Comment: i guess i just need to find a facebook master to look at my project because i think there is more it can do if written correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify, I went back and looked through the documentation and you can get the number of likes on a post. Where were you looking? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: maybe im using the wrong word.  im looking for interests.  you know, the music, books, movies, etc.

Comment: You can get that information via the graph api's connections http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: 2017 here. Do you know more about this? - It seems that you can't get public data from other users! only if the user has the access token (it means only when he give your app the access) can someone confirm this?